# Ideal AWS setup for multiple development teams

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have multiple development teams working different modules for my startup. I created different AWS accounts to separate dev, staging and prod. The development teams only have access to the "dev" environment. However, I need to separate access for these dev teams within the same "dev" aws account as well.

Can I limit Group/Policy access to specific AWS region so they create the AWS resources (lambda, dynamo, apig, s3) in their own region. This seemed like a promising idea but each dev team to a region seems likes an overkill and not efficient.

Is there any other way to create logical spaces within the same AWS account.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the consolidated billing feature in AWS Organizations to consolidate payment for multiple AWS accounts or multiple AISPL accounts. Each organization in AWS Organizations has a master account that pays the charges of all the member accounts. This can help you save cost on AWS billing.

   2. With Condition in AWS IAM Roles and Policy, you can control access to specific AWS regions. For examples: `"Condition": {"StringEquals": {"aws:RequestedRegion": "eu-central-1"}}`

More details are at [Easier way to control access to AWS regions using IAM policies](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easier-way-to-control-access-to-aws-regions-using-iam-policies/)

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you. This second link looks promising. I will check it out.